# Why is this scalar distributed over an area this way?

Tags: integration

I am going through some code where the total thrust $T_0$ is said to be distributed by the radial function

$$ T(r) = T_0 (c_0 + c_1 r^2 + c_2 r^4)$$

However in the code, the actual distribution is normalised such that

$$ T(r) = T_0 \left(\frac{c_0 + c_1 r^2 + c_2 r^4}{c_0+c_1 \frac{R^2}{2}+c_2 \frac{R^4}{3}}\right)$$
where $0\leq r \leq R$.

I don't understand where this denominator comes from. More generally, how can we distribute an integrated quantity over an area by an arbitrary function?

Many thanks for any explanations.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you for your reply. I'm probably missing something very obvious but if I let $r=R$ in the 2nd equation I don't get 1 in the brackets? I suppose what I am asking is if the numerator was say $c_0+c_1 r^3+c_2/2 r^5$ or $c_0 + c_1\sin{r} + c_2\cos{r}$ (or any arbitrary function) what should the denominator be? I'm just not sure how they figured out what the normalization should be.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. What happens when you solve for $c_i$? I imagine that it was chosen so that $\int_0^R T\:dr = T_0$ (This is without their normalization). Do they mention anywhere if the normalization is done with the integral or something else?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks again for your reply. The code is poorly documented but the integral you wrote out makes physical sense as the code solves for the case of uniform thrust ($T(r)=T_0$) and then separately for the radially distributed thrust for comparison. So it makes sense that the integrated thrust should be the same. Do you know how I can use that integral to figure out the normalization from the numerator?

Comment: I think there's one detail I'm missing that prevents me from answer your question, what is $T_0$ or its physical dimensions, are they supposed to match $T$? If they aren't, then shouldn't the uniform thrust case take the form of $T(r) = \frac{T_0}{R}$? If you could describe the relevant quantities or context in more detail, I could probably piece it together since my background is in physics.

Comment: @NinadMunshi $T_0$ is the thrust (Newtons) which is specified by the user. There is an option in the code (which the user can decide on) to either distribute the thrust uniformly over $0\leq r \leq R$ (i.e $T_0$ everywhere) or distribute the thrust according to the function in my question, so I suppose that $T$ must also have the same units (Newtons).

Comment: That last part doesn't make any sense to me. If you're distributing *something* over *anything* that would create a density, not an object with the same dimensions as the *something*

Comment: Actually I think might have found a resolution to the issue. Assuming this is over a circular region, getting the actual total thrust out means that the "real" density would be $2\pi\cdot T(r)\cdot r$ to account for the polar Jacobian. In this case having $T(r) = T_0$ and integrating it would give us $\pi T_0\cdot R^2$. But I can't say anything for sure. It is easy to verify something is correct, but I cannot conclude something is "wrong" because not enough details about the situation have been provided. You've told me what the code is but not what it represents, or what you're modeling.